# Writing Soap Envelope using C#

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I need to write the following xml file from my c# application. Obviously I can use a StringBuilder to construct the string and then write it to a file. But I'm thinking if there is a neater way like using some the .Net classes to construct this content. I have tried the XmlSerializer and XmlSerializerNamespaces but didn't seem to have much luck.
Thank for your help. Sample code is greatly appreciated!

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://something.com/MyStuff" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
<soapenv:Header /> 
  <soapenv:Body>
    <cus:MyFeature>
      <cus:ABC>text1</cus:ABC> 
        <tem:MyHost>
          <tem:MyHostID>text2</tem:MyHostID>
          <tem:MyHostDetail>
            <tem:Item1>text3</tem:Item1>
            <tem:Item2>text4</tem:Item2> 
        </tem:MyHostDetail>
      </tem:MyHost>
    </cus:MyFeature>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Instead of "writing a SOAP envelope", you should use "Add Service Reference" and get a class created that will allow you to call that service just as if it were a normal class.

Comment: The comment above should be the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of "writing a SOAP envelope", you should use "Add Service Reference" and get a class created that will allow you to call that service just as if it were a normal class.